# Assets not load properly when set slash in url

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

How to set htaccess that can load assets even url using slash (/) (only parameter/not sub folder)

Assets directory:

```
http://localhost/assets/images/
http://localhost/assets/js/
http://localhost/assets/css/
```

For All product category

```
http://localhost/products
```

For my product detail:

```
http://localhost/products/seo1
http://localhost/products/seo2
http://localhost/products/seo3
```

If i access http://localhost/products the assets load perfectly but if i access http://localhost/products/seo1 the assets not load properly, if i inspect element, that show http://localhost/products/assets/images/

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?mode=web&module=main [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ index.php?mode=web&module=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/([\w-]+)$ index.php?mode=web&module=productDetail&seo=$1 [L]
```

Just newbie, thank you for helping

Comment: remove this line `RewriteRule ^products/([\w-]+)$ index.php?mode=web&module=productDetail&seo$1 [L]`

Comment: sorry, i have update my question

Comment: hey bro.
you can set the assests in html file.its easy and useful

Comment: I dare say that you are using relative path for the references in your html files. Use absolute paths instead, so paths starting with a `/`, all anchored at the same root directory level.